# Why does changing the Host header in HttpRequest affect server response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, response-headers

In my web API I am enriching and forwarding a POST requests to another URL.
Postman is used for making the Post request.

Operation: POST to http://private.store.internal/api/pay

The request is forwarded to a payments-server. For testing I specified "www.google.com" as the URL where the request should be forwarded to (which of course cannot do anything with the post request)

```
var newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, request.DesiredDestination);
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(newRequest, cancellation);
```

When I inspect the "newRequest" variable the Headers collection contains the "Host" field, which holds the value of the URL, where my API is hosted f.e.

```
private.store.internal
```

This is as expected, the returned headers from the google server are:

```
 "responseHeaders": [
        {
            "key": "Referrer-Policy",
            "value": [ "no-referrer" ]
        },
        {
            "key": "Alt-Svc",
            "value": ["quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"41,39,38,37,35\""]
        },
        {
            "key": "Date",
            "value": ["Wed, 25 Oct 2017 12:15:57 GMT" ]
        },
        {
            "key": "Content-Length",
            "value": ["1561"]
        },
        {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": ["text/html; charset=UTF-8"]
        }
    ],
    "content": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n...
```

Now I don't want to forward the information where the API is hosted to the (real) payments server, so I simply removed the "Host" field:

```
newRequest.Headers.Remove("Host");
```

But this changes the behaviour of the server where the request is forwarded to.
Now the response is

```
 "responseHeaders": [
        {
            "key": "X-XSS-Protection",
            "value": ["1; mode=block"]
        },
        {
            "key": "X-Frame-Options",
            "value": ["SAMEORIGIN"]
        },
        {
            "key": "Alt-Svc",
            "value": ["quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"41,39,38,37,35\""]
        },
        {
            "key": "Date",
            "value": ["Wed, 25 Oct 2017 12:18:52 GMT"]
        },
        {
            "key": "Server",
            "value": ["gws"]
        },
        {
            "key": "Content-Length",
            "value": ["1589"]
        },
        {
            "key": "Allow",
            "value": ["GET","HEAD"]
        },
        {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": ["text/html; charset=UTF-8"]
        }
    ],
    "content": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1
```

which is totally different. My question is: Why does changing/removing the Host property (=where my API is calling from) change the response of the web server?

Comment: Can you go into more detail why you think you need to do `newRequest.Headers.Remove("Host");`?

Comment: Because I don't want that the payment providers (3rd party API) know from where the call is coming from. I don't want to expose the name of an internal server.

Comment: What is the value of the Host header before you remove it?

Comment: "private.store.internal", which is one of our internal servers. Btw. when I specify some random string here like "qwpxoeirsuras.com" the web server sends the expected response. Only when I remove the header, the server sends the "wrong" response. So I don't see why there is a difference between sending "crap" and sending nothing in the Host-Header.

Comment: The Host header represents details of the resource being requested, not the caller. Your code above doesn't seem to set the Header, so I am surprised you need to remove it. Is there some other code you have where you are setting `Headers` of `newRequest`.

Comment: What is the value of `request.DesiredDestination`?

Comment: The host header property is set automatically by asp.net, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host(v=vs.110).aspx
It says "If the Host property is not set, then the Host header value to use in an HTTP request is based on the request URI." The value of "request.DesiredDestination" is the URL of the payment provider to which the request should be forwarded to f.e. http://www.paypal.com

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious. The web server that you make request on is dependent on what headers, methods and etc you send. For example some web-servers would block requests without `HOST` header, because it could be a vulnerability.

Comment: I understand that the behavior of the server depends f.e. on the "Accept-Encoding" field but why does it depend on the Host field? When my app is hostet on "www.server1.com" and I am making a call to the API, this is my host - when my app is hosted on server "www.anotherserver2.com", this address would appear in the host field but how and why should this influence the behavior of the server that gets the request?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23 certainly implies that Host is mandatory in some contexts @HannesB .

Comment: Found this out too. Interestingly it's mandatory but it can contain basically everything like "asdfasdf.com", which seems strange for me.